# The keydown function isn’t working for me

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have KeyPreview on true. Also, I tried making keydown print something with console.writeline and adding a breaking point, but it didn’t even run that. So basically, the function just isn’t running at all.  Also, keyup isn’t working either.

```
 Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, Input As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If Input.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.Y = 0
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.Y = 0
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.X = 0
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.X = 0
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.E Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, Input As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If Input.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.Y = Speed * -1
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.Y = Speed
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.X = Speed * -1
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        FedexMobile.Speed.X = Speed
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.O Then
        If Speed > 0 Then
            Speed = Speed - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
        If Speed < 10 Then
            Speed = Speed + 1
        End If
    ElseIf Input.KeyCode = Keys.E Then

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the `[visual-studio]` tag is for questions about using the Visual Studio application, not code you write with it. You actually missed the main tag that your question needed: `[vb.net]`. Also, is this WinForms code?

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the heads up. Also, it is for windows, yes.

Comment: No. I'm not asking if it's for _Wndows_. I'm asking if the UI technology you are using is "Windows Forms" (as opposed to "WIndows Pesentation Framework", or some other third party UI library).

Comment: Oh. I honestly don’t know. It’s Windows Form project, but I’m very new to visual studios/visual basics.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I've added the `[winforms]` tag to your question. :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is your issue, but simply writing a method called `Form1_KeyDown` doesn't subscribe it as a handler for the `KeyDown` event of `Form1`. Did you generate these methods from the Events tab (lightning icon) in the Form's properties?

Comment: @Llama _"but simply writing a method called Form1_KeyDown doesn't subscribe it as a handler for the KeyDown"_ It _should_ in this case because of the `Handles` clause.

Comment: Ooo. I could try that. I’m not sure if this is what you mean, but I double clicked the event to created the sub.

Comment: @Fungi The first thing you should do is add a breakpoint at the first line in the method and see if it gets triggered (hint: it should).

Comment: @41686d6564 Oh, I see. My bad. I didn't realise that VB.NET worked like that for event subscriptions. It has been a long time since I've used it to be honest.

Comment: Hmmm. It’s alright. I’m really stumped here. I’m more of a Lua person, and Luas way different than this.

Comment: How long does it usually take for these things to be solved?

Comment: Can you try @41686d6564's suggestion of setting a breakpoint? I'd set it on the `If` line, rather than inside the body of the if statement. It seems odd that it's not working, since it appears to be hooked up correctly. Do you have some other control on the form focused, rather than the form itself?

Comment: @JohnG The OP said _"I have KeyPreview on true"_ (which will make the event fire even if the focus is on another control). Unfortunately, this question is unanswerable without debugging details.

Comment: @41686d6564 ... Thanks I did not see that.

Comment: Ye, Lama. I tried breakpoits on the if line. Didn't break.

Answer (score 0):

Check what control is currently focused. The Keys.Up, .Down, .Left and .Right KeyDown-Events only fire when there is no currently focused interaction-control, doesn't matter if KeyPreview is true or false. I don't know a "real" solution for this problem, but you can avoid it by adding a Label without text to your form and setting the TabIndex of this Label to 0.

Comment: What do you mean 'Control is focused on'? xD. Im new to visual studios.

Comment: For example, if a Button is focused it has these blue borders to signal your "standing" on it. In a TextBox you can see a blinking, vertical line which points out your current position

Answer (score 0):

Well... If you cant get it to work, then you should be able to override the `ProcessCmdKey` and It should capture all the keys pressed by the user. I do not necessarily recommend this, however it will fire when any key is pressed. What you currently have technically "should" work as it did in my tests.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  Debug.WriteLine("KeyData is: " & keyData.ToString())
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of "Input" argument variable. *Input* is a VB command.